# when dispatcher parameter destroy using phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

When Dispatcher forward to another action, parameter can pass as dispatcher params. **When the parameter destroy?**

Comment: Please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: got it. thanks brother

Comment: No problem :] and Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

When there will be next forward or anything like this to another action. Like next iterate in dispatcher loop.